# How to select different objects and name them in blender 2.76b

Tags: objects, selection-tools

I am new to blender and learning from a few tutorials. But the tutorials are of the older versions. I am having difficulty selecting and naming different objects. If I want to select a particular object, how will I do it?

Answer (score 6):

In Blender, by default, selection is done by right clicking on an object.  (It seems weird but there are some good workflow reasons for this.)  You can change this under *File* > *User Preferances* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) > *Input* tab.

[image]

You can change the name of an object at the top of the *Object* properties tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be worth pointing out also, that by pressing N to open the properties panel, you can scroll down to rename the object with it selcted. [image: GIF to help explain how to name objects]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *Outliner*:

[image]

Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> (Left Mouse Button) the name to select the item.
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to add selection,

[image]

Double click <kbd>LMB</kbd> to rename.

[image]